# os.join.path does change directory

Tags: python, path, filepath

Hello I have a piece of code where I want to join a path with a picture name which I am getting from an excel file. The thing is that my code changes my path string.

```
src=os.path.join('C:\\Users\\ekrem\\Desktop\\Distributions\\16-17',ws.cell(row=cell.row,column=2).value)
print('src=',src)
```

so here my src variable should be something like this:

```
C:\Users\ekrem\Desktop\Distributions\16-17\26231043_1686575684735993_7548330554586169888_n.jpg
```

but as you see I printed the src variable and I got this

```
src= C:\Users\ekrem\Desktop\16-17\26231043_1686575684735993_7548330554586169888_n.jpg
```

here the distribution folder is missing, have you any idea why?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the result from `ws.cell` in this case?

Comment: Does the `ws.cell` value start with `..\..`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case assuming the end piece is always a single filename it might be easier to do this with f-strings. That way there is no path weirdness that happens something like this should work (Assuming you're on python 3.6+, if you aren't then do [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format) instead):

```py
src = f'C:\\Users\\ekrem\\Desktop\\Distributions\\16-17\\{ws.cell(row=cell.row,column=2).value}'

print(f'{source=}') # Print source with label
```

**P.S** I would recommend switching the `C:\\Users\\<name>` with `%USERPROFILE%` (so `%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\Distributions\\16-17\\`), that way if you change accounts or hard-drives this still works.

Then just do validation with:

```py
if os.path.exists(src):
    # Do stuff
else:
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"{src} file could not be found")
```